# Do values whose pointers are in arrays persist

Tags: c, pointers

Consider the following code

```
int* a[5];

void f() {
    int i = 50;
    a[0] = &i;
}

void main() {
    f();
    printf("%d", *a[0]);
}
```

When `i` goes out of scope, does it get unloaded, and the pointer becomes invalid, or does the value remain?

Comment: Pleasae provide a [mre] to demonstrate the situation your are discussing. As shown it is not even clear whether `i` is global.

Comment: @Yunnosch edited the code

Comment: Note that this code may in fact output `50`. That does not mean it is correct. Such is the nature of undefined behavior.

Comment: Your question is not clear. As [Eugene Sh.’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65360280/298225) states, the **value of the pointer**, `a[0]`, is indeterminate after `f` returns, so `*a[0]` does not even necessarily point to the memory that used to be reserved for `i`. But it seems like you may be asking about the thing that `a[0]` pointed to, `i`, and attempting to refer to it with `*a[0]`. In the C model, `i` no longer exists after the function returns, and the behavior of using `*a[0]` is not defined. (Also note `main` should be defined as `int main(void)`, not `void main()`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [C11 standard draft section **6.2.4 Storage durations of objects**](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.4)

> ...The value of a pointer becomes **indeterminate** when the object it
> points to (or just past) reaches the end of its lifetime.

Therefore the standard is explicitly stating that the value is not guaranteed to be preserved.

Answer (score 2):

When the life-time of `i` ends (as `f` returns) any pointer to it becomes invalid and should not be dereferenced.

Any attempt to dereference invalid pointers leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: This does not clearly answer the question, which asks not just about what the pointer points to but the value of the pointer, although there may be some language issues clouding the intent. As [Eugene Sh.’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65360280/298225) states, the value is indeterminate. Not only dereferencing it would have undefined behavior, but just using the value (for example, by comparing it to `NULL`) is improper.